# laravel destroy function generate wronge url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is my code:

```
{{link_to_route('actions.destroy', 'Delete', $action->id, array('class' => 'myButton2'))}}
```

This is the generated url:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8082/myProjectName/public/actions/1" class="myButton2">Delete</a>
```

It is wrong url.

how to fix it please?

Thanks

Comment: It's generating exactly what you told it to generate. What output are you expecting?

Comment: Can you post your routes file?

Comment: @LifeQuery I wanted to have a url to delete the resouce

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent you really can't do that with a link. You need a form so that you can use the `DELETE` HTTP verb.

Comment: @Raphael_ this is the route ` Route::resource('actions', 'ActionController');`

Comment: @Raphael_ no please :( isn't there any work arround? and why do I need a form?

Comment: Actually @Raphael_ "Delete" is the title of the link :P

Comment: @martinezjc, she's using resourceful controllers though, and those require the destroy method to have a DELETE HTTP Method.

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent because you need to specify the HTTP Verb to be `DELETE` and AFAIK, links are always sent using `GET`. You could make a form with only a submit button and style it using CSS to make it look like a link. I think that would achieve the effect you want.

Comment: @Raphael_ I would prefer to create my own route and make it works with GET `a`

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent that works as well.

Comment: Instead she can use this route: `Route::get('delete', 'Controller@delete');` in the controller you can put the delete function that follows the `@` in my example route. Then in the view: `{{ action('Controller@view', array('id' => $id) ) }}`

Comment: @martinezjc that is whay I already suggested :)

Comment: my comment appears after you write your idea, sorry :P

Comment: @martinezjc don't be sorry please. I am very thankful to your efforts and your attempts to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a submit button by opening a form :

```
{{Form::open(array('route' =>array('actions.destroy',$action->id),'method'=>'delete', 'class' => 'delete'))}}
{{Form::submit('delete')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

And in your controller do not forget to add:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Yourtable::destroy($id);
}
```